# Python: Capture and return each element in quantifier

Tags: python, regex

Given a set of strings like this: `60=60`, `100=60+30+10`, `200=120+50+30`, `300=200+100`, `180=60+50+40+20+10` I need a regex to parse (and validate) these strings. The match should be strict (e.g., no spaces allowed between numbers and operators).

I ended up with a regex like `(\d+)=(\d+)(?:\+(\d+))*`

It matches them all perfectly, but extracting matches with `re.match(regex, string).groups()` returns `('100', '60', '10')`, `('200', '120', '30')`, ...

See, `*` quantifier matched only the last number! That's expected, but doesn't solve my problem.

What is the most pythonic way to return all matches under `*` quantifier separately? So I could easelly `assert res[0] == sum(res[1:])`

Currently, I match each bit independently, storing last match position and continue parsing from that position, but it looks a bit ugly.

Comment: Are there always two `+` operators?

Comment: No, I'll add more examples

Comment: See my post below. you can easily evaluate +- and decimal numbers too without much difficulty.

Comment: Why no spaces allowed between numbers and operators. Is it too complicated that way? Are you validating or parsing ??

Comment: Your not going to get _all_ the RHS values individually with Pythons regex engine. Just match it like this `(\d+)=(\d+(?:\+\d+)*)`, group 1 is the LHS, group 2 must be split on `+` to form an array. Sum up the array,  compare it with the LHS value.

Answer (score 3):

And what about not using regex, but use a parser instead?

```
from pyparsing import *

integer = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda t:int(t[0]))
variable = Word(alphas,exact=1)
operand = integer | variable

expop = Literal('^')
signop = oneOf('+ -')
multop = oneOf('* /')
plusop = oneOf('+ -')
factop = Literal('!')
equalop = Literal('=')

expr = operatorPrecedence( operand,
    [("=", 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
     ("+", 2, opAssoc.RIGHT),]
    )


test=['60=60', '70=10+20', '100=1+2+42+67']

for t in test:
    print t, u'→', expr.parseString(t)
    print
```

which would then output:

```
60=60 → [[60, '=', 60]]

70=10+20 → [[[70, '=', 10], '+', 20]]

100=1+2+42+67 → [[[100, '=', 1], '+', [2, '+', [42, '+', 67]]]]
```

Then to get the integers, you'd only have to flatten the tree, and lookup all integers.

---

Another way, which I find slightly less elegant and does not do syntax checking of the string, would be to split the string on `+` and `=`:

```
for t in test:
    head, tail = t.split('=')
    values = [head] + tail.split('+')
    print t, u'→', values
```

which gives:

```
60=60 → ['60', '60']
70=10+20 → ['70', '10', '20']
100=1+2+42+67 → ['100', '1', '2', '42', '67']
```

Finally, we could try to find a regex magic bullet to answer your question, but honestly, that wouldn't be the way I'd solve this.

---

N.B.: to flatten a list, here's a way:

```
def flatten(seq):
    res = []
    for item in seq:
        if (isinstance(item, (tuple, list))):
            res.extend(flatten(item))
        else:
            res.append(item)
    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

If `+` is the only operator that you can get, (as I assume from the fact that you mentioned `sum()`), you need no regex.  Just use regular `.split()`:

```
total, expression = string.split("=")
assert int(total.strip()) == sum(int(x.strip()) for x in expression.split("+"))
```

Comment: It will match strings with spaces `100 = 50 + 30 + 20`, but they should fail

Comment: @dmzkrsk: Okay.  I added `.strip()`

Comment: Wait a minute.  Do you *want* it to fail?  It would have the way I had it, but now I changed it and I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try python builtin function `eval` to evaluate an expression at run-time. I have changed regex to little bit. It's general purpose and can be easily adopted to any mathematical operation.

```
import re

data = "100=60+30+10, 200=120+50+30, 300=200+100, 180=60+50+40+20+10"

rx = r"(\d+)=([^, ]+)"

for res in re.finditer(rx, data, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE):
    lhs = eval(res.group(1))
    rhs = eval(res.group(2))
    assert lhs == rhs
```

And if you want some fun with code snippet, replace regex with:

```
rx = r"([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+))=([^, ]+)"
```

Now you can evaluate positive, negative, integer and decimal numbers too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems easy to solve using regex (Python 2.7):

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = '60=60, 100=60+30+10, 200=120+50+30, 300=200+100, 180=60+50+40+20+10'
>>> pattern = '((?:\d+)(?:|\+)|(?=|\+)(?:\d+))'
>>> [re.findall(pattern, str) for str in strs.split(',')]
[['60', '60'], ['100', '60', '30', '10'], ['200', '120', '50', '30'], ['300', '200', '100'], ['180', '60', '50', '40', '20', '10']]
```

[REGEX DEMO.](https://regex101.com/r/hP2yK1/2)